# Check distance between two location In KM

Tags: swift

I want my distance to have in Kilo-meters between two given latitude and longitude

```
 func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        if isSetDestination{
            
            destinationField.text = place.formattedAddress
            destinationLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
            destinationLongitutude = place.coordinate.longitude
            setNewLoaction(lat:  destinationLatitude!, long: destinationLongitutude!, markerTitle: "Destination Location")
            
        }else{
            
            pickUpField.text = place.formattedAddress
            pickUpLatitude = place.coordinate.latitude
            pickUpLongitutude = place.coordinate.longitude
            setNewLoaction(lat:  pickUpLatitude!, long: pickUpLongitutude!, markerTitle: "Pick up Location")
            
        }
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I am using GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate to get lat and long

Comment: `CLLocation` already provides a `distance(from:` API which returns the distance between `CLLocation` in meters so `loc1.distance(from: loc2) / 1000.0` should return you distance in KM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   let locA = CLLocation(latitude: pickUpLatitude!, longitude: pickUpLongitutude!)
            let locB = CLLocation(latitude: destinationLatitude!, longitude: destinationLongitutude!)
            let distance = locA.distance(from: locB) / 1000
            
            if distance >= 2000{
                NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "Destination is too far!")
            }else{
               }
```

import CoreLocation and you will be able to do that! :)